# Access to magnetometer from javascript on iphone/ipad

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, html, ipad

I want the direct output of the magnetometer into a javascript event handler function on my iphone/ipad.
But, the HTML5 deviceOrientation API unfortunately combines info from several sensors. 
Is there a better Javascript API for the magenetometer? How to tackle this?

Comment: What do you need it for?

Comment: for the precise sensor reading of orientation of the magnetic north and field strength. The equivalent to Objective-C CLLocationManager  functionality